# How to support thousands of files using Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, bulk

I'm using Inno Setup to write an installer for an application based on Node.js. Then our node application (including modules) consists of almost 4,000 files. The installer needs to copy all of these files, as well as remove them during uninstallation.

I've already written this to use a ZIP file which gets extracted during installation, and recursively delete files during the uninstall. But I would have to write a tremendous amount of code to be able to properly handle file copy/replace/delete operations, while I could register them in my Inno Setup script and let the installer do all that work (as it's designed to do). The problem with that is I'm not about to manually write almost 4k lines of code (and manage them when frequent additions are made) for each file. I could write a small app to iterate through the files and write ISS script, but that's another project I'm not about to start.

Is there a way to not only add, but manage groups of files in bulk in recursive folders? Perhaps a custom IDE meant for this?

Comment: I would assume it is possible to tell InnoSetup to use a directory as a source for the installer, instead of the individual files in that folder.

If you look here: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection it looks like Inno Setup supports specifying directories as a source. Does this do what you're looking for?

Comment: `Source: "C:\DirWith1000FilesAndFolders\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion createallsubdirs recursesubdirs` - all files and folders will be included and then deleted during uninstall. You can Exlude files on demand with `Excludes: "list of file to be excluded"`

Comment: Note that you only need the `createallsubdirs` flag if you want to preserve empty dirs, which is rarely necessary in practice but everyone seems to include it anyway without thinking about it. :)

Comment: @Miral - there are apps that do need empty dirs :) Try to play e.g. Gothic 1 without `Saves` folder - game will crash on saving as it is unable to create (in fact Move) Current Savegame Folder to `Saves` directory if it doesn't exist. So it is safer way to create even empty dirs if you do not fully know how does specific app work.

Comment: I know they do exist, but they shouldn't. :)  It's something to fix rather than something to enshrine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There are many way to add all files to inno setup:

- You can use `Flags: recursesubdirs`;

For example:

```
    [Files]
    Source: "C:\Source Folder\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
```

- You can use [inno setup quick start pack](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php)
- You can install Only [Istool](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Authoring-tools/Setup-creators/ISTool.shtml)
- TO put files in Istool open Files and directory section in Istool Drag and drop all (Select Thousand of files or Folder if any with Ctrl+A)
  Thousand Of files in the Files and directory section of Istool and save.

PS: If you use Istool then save the Documents and open with inno setup.
I personaly Use Istool.
Thanks

Comment: Flags like..., etc. ? Well, show us more of them... FYI, `recursesubdirs` if for including files from all the subdirectories of the given path (by the given file pattern) and `createallsubdirs` includes (and creates on the target system) also subdirectories that remained empty after that inclusion. Finally, those flags have no meaning for a single file. Well, I see that deployment is underestimated by many developers, but it's the important part of software development where you must fully understand what you are doing. It's not about *put some flags, etc.*.

Comment: Thanks for informing me. I am not a master of inno setup,I am useing inno setup for only 1 year, so I may not know everything about inno setup.

Comment: It was good to suggest `recursesubdirs` in the first place. You don't need any 3rd party tool for that. Just without an example that was for a single file and rather without `createallsubdirs` flag (as that flag is not wanted in most of the cases as it creates empty subfolders).

Comment: @Tlama I think Istool is easy to use ,and it has every option,so you don;t  have to write all the code by hand. what do you think?

Comment: I think that most (if not all) people here would agree that as first you should mention built-in options. After that you might mention 3rd party tools (if there are no built-in options, or they're worth mentioning). I'm not using ISTool, so cannot comment this option. But still, it's like when someone asked you to get to point B which would be 200m from point A and you would suggest them taking a taxi even though they could walk there :-)

Comment: @Tlama Ok , I get it what are you trying to say.I edited The answer.Thanks.